# Привязать дочерний элемент к родительскому CSS

Tags: css3

Делаю раздел новостей. Каждая новость состоит из картинки и заголовка. Заголовок должен быть прозрачным и находиться на самой картинке. Но у меня получается эффект, что заголовок вылезает за пределы картинки. Использую bootstrap. Подскажите как справиться с этой бедой.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .news_main_page_tip {   color: #ffffff; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); font-family: 'Marmelad', sans-serif; font-size: 13pt;}
    .news_main_page_tip2 {position: absolute;  bottom: 0px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
    </style>

</head>
<body>



<div id="wrapper" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 font block main_page_tabls"><center><b>Новости</b></center></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 "><div class="news_main_page_tip"><img src="img/n1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> <div class="news_main_page_tip2"> Проверка тестового заголовка новости, которая вышла сегодня утром </div> </div> </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 "><div class="news_main_page_tip"><img src="img/n1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> Проверка тестового заголовка новости, которая вышла сегодня утром </div> </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 "><div class="news_main_page_tip"><img src="img/n1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> Проверка тестового заголовка новости, которая вышла сегодня утром </div> </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.news_main_page_tip {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Marmelad",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}
.news_main_page_tip img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.news_main_page_tip2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 font block main_page_tabls">
   <center><b>Новости</b></center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
   <div class="news_main_page_tip">
    <img src="images/sl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="news_main_page_tip2"> Проверка тестового заголовка новости, которая вышла сегодня утром </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
   <div class="news_main_page_tip">
    <img src="images/sl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="news_main_page_tip2"> Проверка тестового заголовка новости, которая вышла сегодня утром </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
   <div class="news_main_page_tip">
    <img src="images/sl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="news_main_page_tip2"> Проверка тестового заголовка новости, которая вышла сегодня утром </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

За один только тег center я бы уволил верстальщика, не говоря уже обо всем остальном))